# Is character same as one dimensional irreducible representation?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Look at character table of the Klein Group:
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_Klein_four-group

Is the plus or minus ones on each row the same as one dimensional irreducible representation? If so, why 1111 can be a representation? How can we tell something about the group elements if 1111 is the representation?

Comment: Yes, the Klein group is abelian so all of its irreducible representations are one-dimensional, and can be identified with their characters. (In fact, this characterises abelian groups.)  The row $1111$ is the (character of) the trivial representation which sends every group element to $1$.  It's true that it is not very interesting, as every group has this representation, and they all look pretty much the same, so all you can really tell from it is the number of conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 3):

A (complex) character of a group $X$ is the trace of a representation $\rho:X \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ for some $n$. Since the trace is conjugation- invariant, so is any character of $X$. A character table of $X$ gives a list of the values of each irreducible character of $X$ on the conjugacy classes of $X$; by Schur's theorem, any arbitrary character of $X$ is a linear combination of irreducible characters.

The group $X = \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ is abelian and thus has only $1$-dimensional irreps; the character of a $1$-dimensional representation $\rho$ is just $\rho$ itself, under the obvious identification $GL_1(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^\times$. Each element of $X$ has order dividing $2$, so each character takes only $\pm 1$ as values. In general, however, characters are not multiplicative (as one would expect, since they're conjugation invariant).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in some contexts, people may indeed use the term character more restrictively to mean a $1$-dimensional representation (and not necessarily complex). In slightly different contexts again, it refers to something that behaves a bit like the character as described here, but is in fact something completely different (this is for example the case when studying reductive algebraic groups).

Comment: Sure. This is kind of character one would encounter in an introductory course on group theory or on the complex representation theory of finite groups, as it looks like the OP is studying.